# Build Docker image for .net core project through command

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, continuous-deployment

I want to create docker image for my .net core project. I already have .net core project created with docker enable feature. If I run project from VS, it automatically creates docker image for me. But I want to create image through docker commands (I don't want to create/run container on my machine, just want to create docker image from source code). I am using docker for windows.

Any help?

Comment: You could always create a template for `dotnet new` which would allow you to stub out a basic dockerfile. Maybe something like `dotnet new dockerfile` could work, but you'll need to create it. I've written about creating custom templates in the past, it might be a useful starting point: https://dotnetcore.gaprogman.com/2017/10/05/creating-a-custom-template/

Comment: @JamieTaylor Thanks for your interest but I am talking about docker image not docker file or template. As mentioned above, I already have docker configured on my project.

Answer (score 1):

You can build the docker image from .net core project in the following way:

1. In your project, you have a docker file which contains information like: (if not then create).

   ```
   FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
   WORKDIR /app
   EXPOSE 80
   EXPOSE 443

   FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
   WORKDIR /src
   COPY TestProject.API/TestProject.API.csproj TestProject.API/
   RUN dotnet restore TestProject.API/TestProject.API.csproj        
   COPY . .        
   WORKDIR /src/TestProject.API        
   RUN dotnet build TestProject.API.csproj -c Release -o /app

   FROM build as unittest        
   WORKDIR /src/TestProject.UnitTest

   FROM build AS publish        
   RUN dotnet publish TestProject.API.csproj -c Release -o /app

   FROM base AS final        
   WORKDIR /app        
   COPY --from=publish /app .        
   ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestProject.API.dll"]
   ```
2. Build the project in the solution or using command via opening the same in command prompt and then use the command:

   E:\TestProject\TestProject.API>docker build .

It will create the image. You can check the same the via command:

```
E:\TestProject\TestProject.API>docker images
```

Comment: Hi, can you please use text for the docker file, instead of an image?  i.e. use the {} icon in the editor.

Comment: I updated the details as a text for the docker file.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) and check that into your source repository if you don't have it already.  This tells docker how to create an image.

Running [docker build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) from the directory with the Dockerfile will build you the image.

You can then execute [docker push](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/) to push that image to a docker repository, or [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) to create a container with that new image.

You'll probably also want to be familiar with [docker images](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/) to list the images on your machine, and [docker rmi](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rmi/) to remove old images.  They build up fast during development so it helps to be on top of that.